# Modal is overlapping the content and making the content unclickable in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have made a modal which is displaying in footer but when the modal appears it overlaps the overall div and make the side bar unclickable.

**Here is the code:**

```
<footer>     
<div class="modal custom show" id="trackModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
                 <div class="modal-dialog" id="popup">
                     <div class="modal-content">
                          <img id="popclose" src="~/Content/MediaCenter/assets/images/cookies.jpg">
                     </div>
                  </div>
        </div>
<footer>
```

**Here is the css**

```
div#popup {
    left: 18%;
}
div#trackModal {
    z-index: 1049;
}

.modal.custom .modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 130%;
    display: none;
}
```

I have tried `visibility:hidden`; `overflow-x:auto` and `overflow-y:auto`. But result remains the same.

Please if anyone can help?

Comment: Please, update your code so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#how-it-works

Comment: ``<div class="modal custom show" id="trackModal"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackModalLabel" aria-hidden="false"  tabindex="-1">`` try adding tabindex="-1" as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use Z-index property to the model like this:

```
   .modal.custom .modal-dialog {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        content: "";
        width: 130%;
        display: none;
        z-index: -1; 
    }
```

so now, side bar will goes front of your model. Try it.